# In C, technical explanation for how %d recognizes variables in a string

Tags: c, string, variables, math

I came across an interesting output and I'd to know how the computer is working to produce this. I know that whenever you have %d in a string, you should have a variable to accompany it. When I wrote  two %d's and only one variable, I expected that the computer would churn out the same value for the %d's, since it had only one variable to draw on, but for some reason, the %d's returned the value for x and the value for the variable xCubed. I want to know why the program returns xCubed without my writing xCubed at the end of the string. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cube(int x);

int main(void){
    int x = 5;
    int xCubed = cube(x);

    printf("Why does this number, %d, equal this number %d?", x);

    return 0;
}

int cube(int x){
    return x * x * x;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `xCubed` happens to be allocated just after `x`, which means closer to the `printf` part of the stack (activation frame).

`printf` is a vararg function, it has no implicit way of knowing how many arguments it was passed. So, when you call `printf` with two placeholders but just one value supplied, it will read past the first argument expecting a second and "fall" into the stack of the caller, whose nearest content is exactly `xCubed`.

Just to be clear: this is the reason why your code exhibits that particular behaviour, not the way it is expected to work. You have a serious bug in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Your program invokes undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. Possibly the valued returned from the call to `cube` happens to lie next to the value of `x` on the stack. Of course, this behaviour being undefined means that any change to your program, or your compiler options, could result in different behaviour.

In any case, you are expected to supply two values. Do so.

```
printf("Why does this number, %d, equal this number %d?", x, x);
```

If you compiled your program with full warnings then the compiler would have warned you of your error. And you could even ask your compiler to treat warnings as errors to stop you committing the mistake.

Comment: There is plenty of point in reasoning about undefined behavior. Some people want to know not just about the C standard but about how processors work, how compilers work, and more. “Undefined behavior”, as it is used so often in this forum, means only that the C standard does not define it, not that other things in the world do not define it.

Answer (score 4):

Your program causes undefined behaviour, so anything is possible.  It's some quirk of stack/register layout and calling convention for your platform that gives you the results you see.

Answer (score 2):

This was by good luck. In effect, it is undefined behaviour.

Obviously, in your case the variable `xCubed` was put onto stack immediately after the free space. Upon doing the `printf()` call, `x` was put immediately before that, and then the address of the format string.

If you compile this program with other optimization settings, your compiler might decide to put `xCubed` somwhere else, or in a register, or omit it altogether, as its value is never used.